# running ant in cygwin return JAVA_HOME incorrect setting

Tags: java, ant

```
$ ant --version

Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute 헬愣헬愣0
헬愣헬愣0
Files
/bin/java
```

I extract Ant into a folder called Ant

```
C:\ANT
```

I set-up the environmental variables

```
ANT_HOME with the path C:\Ant

JAVA_HOME with the path C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_32

I checked my Java path is set correctly 
and does return the correct message.

java version "1.6.0_27"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_27-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.2-b06, mixed mode)
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can also in `cygwin` just go to

```
cd /cygdrive/c
ln -s /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/jdk-xxx java
```

and update `.bashrc`

```
export JAVA_HOME="/cygdrive/c/java"
export ANT_HOME="/cygdrive/c/ant"
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin
```

Comment: `PATH` yes, but `JAVA_HOME` must be a Windows-style path rather than a `/cygdrive` one as Java is not Cygwin-aware.

Answer (score 0):

Not a final solution, but could not put in comments.

1. Install jdk to c:/apps/jdk1.6.0_32 (a path without space)
2. set JAVA_HOME=c:/apps/jdk1.6.0_32
3. set ANT_HOME=c:/ant (your already have this)
4. run $ANT_HOME/bin/ant

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all these tips but nothing worked to solve the above mentioned issue:

> Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.

Then I realized that at **`ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES`** menu, although **`JAVA_HOME`** path appeared without semi-colon (`;`) at the end of the string, viewing on the text editor panel, it was there, then removing the semi-colon everything worked fine !

[image]

BTW, I'm running under Windows 10.

Comment: I guess it is an issue on Apache ANT, I've never faced the same with any other Java compiler.